# nothing being added to the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
    $mname=$_POST['sub'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['pos']))
    {
    $pos=$_POST['pos'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rad1']))
    {
    $vis=$_POST['rad1'];
    }

    global $mname, $pos, $vis;

    $q= "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name, position, visible) VALUES ('$mname', '$pos', '$vis')";
    $qs=mysql_query($q, $connection);
    if($qs)
    {       
            header("Location: content.php");
            exit;
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }

?>
```

- I get sub, pos and rad1 from a form
- my database's primary key is auto-incrementing but rows are empty

Where is the mistake?

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: In your <form , is the `method` specified as `post` ?

Comment: yes. method is post in my form

Comment: Hi can you post your Form?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it should be working properly

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("test");
  $mname='abc';
  $pos='13';
  $vis='true';

  $q= "INSERT INTO subjects (`menu_name`, `position`, `visible`) VALUES ('".$mname."', '".$pos."', '".$vis."')";
  $qs=mysql_query($q);
  if($qs)
    {       
            //header("Location: db.php");
            exit;
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: generally, its working alright. This particular code isn't working.i'm using wamp2.2

Comment: check your php version in wamp 2.2

Comment: i am using wampserver 2.5 Apache-2.4.9 Mysql-5.6.17 php5.5.12-32b

Comment: **mysql desprication** Mysql will be removed soon, why would you advice OP to use it?

Comment: now i am using pdo or cakephp but the guy ask the question related to mysql

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your *$_POST* array is empty. 
Do a

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);  
exit();
?>
```

This way we can know if are you getting an empty *$_POST*.